# Angular 10 - detect if image exists on client side only, else default image

Tags: angular, image, rest, url

I need to know how to detect if an image exists, on client-side only, with Angular. I have heard that we can set a default image with the timeout function, but I don't know how to catch 404 errors.

I need to write the code on the getResourceImg() only, as the [angular's style guide says](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-17)

**resource-ui.component.ts**

```
  @Input() resource: IResourcePublished;
  // ...

  resourceImgUrlLogoDefault: string = 'assets/images/logo_default.png';
  resourceImgUrl: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resourceImgUrl = this.getRessourceImg(this.resource);
  }

  getResourceImg(resource: IResourcePublished): string {

    return 'assets/images/screen-resources/' + resource.id + '.png';
  }

  //..
```

Here's the template (generated with a `*ngFor="let resource of resources"`) :

**resource-ui.component.html**

```html
<div class="card" [style.background]="categoryColor">
  <div class="card-header" ngbTooltip="More infos" (click)="openResourceDetails()">
    <img
    class="layout-img img-fluid"
    [src]="resourceImgUrl"
    alt="resource-{{resource.id}}"
    />
  </div>
  <!-- ... --> 
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `return resource.id ? 'assets/images/screen-resources/' + resource.id + '.png': resourceImgUrlLogoDefault`

Comment: @KamranKhatti not really because the id itself (fetched from the rest api) exists always. In this case, it is the **local images** that I need to verify.
Ex: 'assets/images/screen-ressources/192.png' does not exists, but 'assets/images/screen-ressources/47.png' exists in my folder.
In fact, it's like a mapping of the local assets images folder with resource's id coming throught API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create reusable directive like:

**fallback-img.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[fallback]'
})
export class FallbackImgDirective {
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('src')
  src: string;

  @Input() fallback: string;

  @HostListener('error')
  onError() {
    this.src = this.fallback;
  }
}
```

Usage

```
<img src="http://unknown/404.jpg" fallback="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/Qt5zl80fgq0Yd6H362H2?open=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: thanks, it is really helpful ! Now, how can the `@HostListener('error') onError() {}` work on the src attribute ? I don't really understand the `@HostBinding('src')` because I haven't been using directives until know.

Comment: HostListener allows us to listen to event for host element. Host element in this case is img which can have error event. HostBinding means that the change for that src field will update src property of host element